Should an error be returned by subscriber when processing a message in an event driven architecture
We are implementing a message broker, and working through some details about subscriber response expectations.  In the event that the subscriber cannot validate the incoming message (or some other error), is it best practice for them to return 200 to stop delivery, or some 4xx to indicate a message failure?  The 4xx would cause the broker to retry several times - not sure this is the best behavior or not.
